# Using splat operator with when

Tags: ruby, splat

Case statement:

```
case x
when 1
  "one"
when 2
  "two"
when 3
  "three"
else
  "many"
end
```

is evaluated using the `===` operator. This operator is invoked on the value of the `when` expression with the value of the `case` expression as the argument. The case statement above is equivalent to the following:

```
if 1 === x
  "one"
elsif 2 === x
  "two"
elsif 3 === x
  "three"
else
  "many"
end
```

In this case:

```
A = 1
B = [2, 3, 4]
case reason
when A
  puts "busy"
when *B
  puts "offline"
end
```

the `when *B` part cannot be rewritten to `*B === 2`.

Is this about the splat operator? The splat operator is about assignment, not comparison.
How does case statement handle `when *B`?

Comment: A minor difference between your first and second example: if `x` is a method, it is only called once in the first example but up to three times in the second example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But the splat operator is about assignment, not comparison.

In this case, `*` converts an [array into an argument list](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion):

```
when *[2, 3, 4]
```

is equivalent to:

```
when 2, 3, 4
```

Just like in a method call:

```
foo(*[2, 3, 4])
```

is equivalent to:

```
foo(2, 3, 4)
```